# Can "these" be used before a number? -- "All these eight years..."

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say "All these eight years"? I mean, I know that it is pretty common to say "all these years" but what about mentioning the number of years?

"**All these eight years**, I was sick of sharks, collecting any piece of information about the great white shark in magazines and books."

Comment: I prefer "For the last eight years…", but that's probably just personal preference. By the way, "I was sick of sharks" means "I had had enough exposure to sharks and no longer wanted to look at them", while the next clause "collecting any piece…" implies that you were actually still very interested. Did you intend for the two halves of the sentence to have opposite meanings?

Comment: What you probably mean is "I was crazy about sharks" or "I was obsessed with sharks".

Comment: I would say "For all of eight years...".

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem in it. It's quite a common style.

> All these eight years, I've been struggling to get out of this problem

'all these' would imply to the entire tenure you are talking about. By numbering, you are just telling a particular span.